# Why are STL algorithms much faster with pointers than std::vector iterators?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, c++builder

Why does `std::nth_element()` run so much faster, when it is given pointers instead of iterators? I would expect `std::vector` and STL algorithms to be quite optimized, but my measurements show execution time drops by 75% when I change iterators to pointers.

Using iterators, the following code (not including allocation of the vector) ran in 1200 milliseconds:

```
std::vector<uint16_t> data(/* 50 million values */);

const double alfa = 0.01;
const double beta = 0.95;

std::nth_element(data.begin(), data.begin() + int(data.size() * alfa), data.end());
const uint16_t x = *(data.begin() + int(data.size() * alfa));

std::nth_element(data.begin(), data.begin() + int(data.size() * beta), data.end());
const uint16_t y = *(data.begin() + int(data.size() * beta));
```

Using pointers, the following code (not including allocation of the vector) ran in 350 milliseconds:

```
std::vector<uint16_t> data(/* 50 million values */);

const double alfa = 0.01;
const double beta = 0.95;

std::nth_element(&data.front(), &data.front() + int(data.size() * alfa),
    &data.front() + data.size());
const uint16_t x = *(data.begin() + int(data.size() * alfa));

std::nth_element(&data.front(), &data.front() + int(data.size() * beta),
    &data.front() + data.size());
const uint16_t y = *(data.begin() + int(data.size() * beta));
```

I observed similar speed increase with `std::sort()` as well. The examples were compiled with Embarcadero C++ Builder XE8 version 22.0.19027.8951, Release build and "Generate fastest possible code" setting. These tests were ran during different executions so they should not affect each other.

Comment: How did you compile your code? Did you use any optimization flag?

Comment: Optimizations are enabled.

Comment: As a sidenote: you store 50 million values for a type which can only have 65536 different values. Consider using a better data-structure for the task.

Comment: Did you try the same benchmark with a different compiler? I can imagine that the compiler doesn't look through [hopefully inline] functions used with iterators. When the compiler does detect that it is contiguous memory (as compilers often can for pointers and, as far as I can tell, also for `std::vector` iterators), it may be able to vectorize some operations gain performance (it could be interesting to see if the improvement is down to vectorization by selectively disabling vectorization; I know [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/) can selectively disable this optimization).

Comment: @KarolyHorvath He meant the vector's size is 50 million.

Comment: @rozina: that was perfectly clear to me.

Comment: My guess is the compiler is either not doing a great job of optimizing or else you are building in debug mode and the compiler uses special, debug (slow), versions of the STL containers.

Comment: @Ville-ValtteriTiittanen If you posted whole test people could copy-paste it, and investigate the issue on other set-ups. Remember that performance is not portable, and all analysis is basically a set-up specific divagation.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Could you explain what you meant then, because I fail to understand and I am interested.

Comment: @rozina: You store the count of each element. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort

Comment: @Galik You are correct about debug mode. It seems that even though I am compiling a Release build, it is possible to enable debug symbols in the settings, and for some reason they were enabled. After disabling this setting, both examples ran in a similar time. If you post that as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: @Ville-ValtteriTiittanen I've ran into this issue myself :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is the compiler is either not doing a great job of optimizing or else you are building in debug mode and the compiler uses special, debug (slow), versions of the STL containers.

Comment: I had gone through all the trouble of seeing what gcc and llvm do with this just to see the problem has already been solved.  Doh!  In testing this, I actually get some weird behaviour.  I get that whichever version I run second is the faster one.

Comment: @GuyGreer There is a definite art to bench testing, I'm still learning pitfalls. Sometimes I can speed up my bench-marks simply by allocating a huge block of memory right at the start and then, immediately, deallocating it.